# routing without traffic in HERE: trafficMode=disabled is unknown?

Tags: here-api

I just reused an old script in which I send a routing request to HERE using '&trafficMode=disabled' in order to not let the current traffic situation affect the results for my general request. HERE now return a notice "The provided parameter 'trafficMode=disabled' is unknown.' which I cannot recall having seen previously.

The results I now get vary slightly over the day and I highly suspect that they are affected by current traffic, which I absolutely want to avoid. My question: if 'trafficMode=disabled' indeed does not work anymore then how do I construct a URL to avoid traffic?

'trafficMode=disabled' doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are still using the older version "v7" of our routing API, please note this service is no longer being actively developed.

We recommend to upgrade to HERE Routing API v8 service **where you can define the departure time as "any" which by default disables the traffic.**

Also sharing the [user guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/departure-time.html) for better understanding.

For more help, here is the [Migration guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/migration_guide/index.html) which will show you how to proceed the upgrade.

Comment: Since the URL I'm using starts with "https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?origin=" I always assumed that I am in fact using API v8...?

Comment: I suppose the HERE developers carried over features from v7 to v8 but "undocumented" and removed them later on. Anyway, departureTime=any works as intended, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When doing some testing of a migration from v7 to v8 routing, the parameter:

&traffic[mode]=disabled

Is supported.